# Implement both of onTouchListner and onLongClickListner for an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I tryed to implement both of `onTouchListner` and `onLongClickListner` for my `ImageView` like this :

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                ShowMessageToast("Long Touch ");
                return true ;
            }

        });
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                action = event.getAction();                  
                    switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                           ShowMessageToast("Down ");
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            ShowMessageToast("Moved ");
                            break;


                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                return true;
            }
```

but the `onLongClickListner` doesn't work until I desactivate `onTouchListner`(//comment).

if the `onTouchListner` is not make as comment (//....) it never display "Long Touch"

`ShowMessageToast("Moved ")` is juste a function to display a message in a Toast.

Comment: The return value indicates if you consume your event or not. You return true so you tell the system that you have handled the event and that it should not be passed further. Return false, and your event will end up in your listener.

Comment: You just mean that I have to return false in onLongTouchListner?

Comment: In your onTouchListener

Comment: Yes it works, but evenif my finger is moving it detects that like a longClick, can I rectify this

Comment: The cleanest way is to check what kind of MotionEvent you are receiving. If you have a MotionEvent that is suitable for you - a long pressed event-, than you return false so it ends up in your longclicklistener. Else return true to consume it. Or.. Handle everything in your onTouchListener itself :). Overall, bad usecase to combine clicklisteners and touchlisteners..

Comment: thank you very much @MartijnVanMierloo, I want to accept your answer, but it is a comment, please I have two last questions, can I add `doubleTap`, and `Fling` event here just like I am doing now, not with creating a new class which implement `OnGestureListener` or `OnDoubleTapListener`. my second question is you said "Handle everything in your onTouchListener itself " how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LongClickListener` and the `TouchListener` interfere with each other as a long click always starts with a touch (`ACTION_DOWN`). What kind of gesture would you like to detect in the `TouchListener`?

If you want (as example) detect long-clicks together with scrolling, then a TouchListener together with a GestureListener would be the way to handle it. Here's an example how to do this:

```
findViewById(R.id.myImageView).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            Log.d("TEST", "onScroll");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener#onLongPress(android.view.MotionEvent)
         */
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("TEST", "onLongPress");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLongPress(e);
        }

        // ... implement here other callback methods like onFling, onScroll as necessary
    });

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Raw event: " + event.getAction() + ", (" + event.getRawX() + ", " + event.getRawY() + ")");
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

**Remarks**

- This implements just the onTouchListener and no `onLonGClickListener` is necessary. The `TouchListener` just passes all touch events to a gesture listener. The gesture listener collects the gestures and calls the callback methods whenever one of the gestures is detected.
- Gestures can be: scroll, fling, tap (click - either confirmed to be not a double tap or without waiting), double-tap, long press.
- My code shows an example for long-press and scrolling. Just implement other callbacks as you need to detect other gestures.

Comment: For good practice, you should not 'return true' hard coded but return the value that you receive from the gestureDectector.onTouchEvent. In other words: return gestureDetector.onTouchEven(event); in the onTouch method

Comment: @martijn-van-mierloo right. I changed it. The code was taken from an example with overlapping views.